# AngularJS. How to refill inputs with the data?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Is it possible and how I can refill data to inputs on webpage after getting this data using ajax?

When I press "get" button, I get data using ajax (get function) and put it to $scope.data of my controller. But on web page you still see Nicolas Cage in inputs as default values. How I can forcibly re-read data and re-fill inputs after "get" function?

My web page is:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.firstname" required>
  <input type='text' ng-model="data.lastname" required>

  <form ng-submit="update()"><input type="submit" value="update"></form>
  <form ng-submit="get()"><input type="submit" value="get"></form>
</div>
```

My js:

```
function MyController($scope) {
  // default data and structure
  $scope.data = {
    "firstname" : "Nicolas",
    "lastname" : "Cage"
  };

  $scope.get = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/php/get_data.php?",
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 10000, // 10 seconds for getting result, otherwise error.
        error:function() { alert("Temporary error. Please try again...");},
        complete: function(){ $.unblockUI();},
        beforeSend: function(){ $.blockUI()},
        success: function(data){
            json_answer = eval('(' + data + ')');
            if (json_answer){
                $scope.data = json_answer;
            }
        }
    });
  };

  $scope.update = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/php/update_data.php?",
        type: "POST",
        data: $scope.data,
        timeout: 10000, // 10 seconds for getting result, otherwise error.
        error:function() { alert("Temporary error. Please try again...");},
        complete: function(){ $.unblockUI();},
        beforeSend: function(){ $.blockUI()},
        success: function(data){ }
    });
  };
```

}

Comment: please dont use $.ajax in angular world angular provides equivelent $http which all provides all features provided by $.ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
     $scope.data = json_answer;
});
```